# Kendo PanelBar with AngularJS ng-Repeat does not render correctly on modifying datasource

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, panelbar

I have problems with Kendo PanelBar in combination with ng-repeat and modifiying dynamically the datasource!

You can see a small demo here:
http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@IT-SCHMITZ/OrEK/2

After clicking the button "Add new album" you can see, that there was added a new item to the panelbar. Unfornately it is not correctly rendered.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work with `ng-repeat` once the widget is initialized.  A workaround would be to use the `dataSource` argument, but since the PanelBar does not currently support a live data source you need to use `k-rebind` to rebuild the widget when the data changed.

Here's an example: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@mishoo/Udep

Comment: I already tested a datasource. By using a datasource I have another problem. I need the double click event on li items. With ng-repeat I can use ng-dblclick. I don't see, how I can do this with datasource, because the panelbar doesn't supports (kendo) templates. Furthermore I'm using ng-repeat with a filter. I don't know how to use this with datasource argument!?

Comment: I see, you have updated the docs for angular-kendo.js (http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/ng-repeat).